# How can I consume a webservice in asp.net web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications

I want to consume a webservice into my web application. The webservice is added at the service reference but I can't seem to use the methods of the webservice.

I've tried it by calling it at the top by using "using ServiceReference1" but the code where I use the methods is giving errors

```
using ServiceReference1;

namespace Book_Club
{

    public partial class Registerpage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        bool register = true;
        //creating WebServiceSoapClient is also giving errors
        WebServiceSoapClient ws = new WebServiceSoapClient();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.BookClubWebService client = 
                new ServiceReference1.BookClubWebService();

            ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = 
                UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
        }

        protected void RegisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                // Allows the user to register. UserAdd is a method in my webservice    
                register = ws.UserAdd(TextBoxName.Text, SurnameTextBox.Text,
                    EmailTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text, 
                    ConfirmPasswordTextBox.Text, TextBoxPasswordQuestion.Text, 
                    TextBoxPasswordAnswer.Text);
                if (register == true)
                {
                    LabelRegister.Text = "Registration Done";
                }
                else
                {
                    LabelRegister.Text = "User already exists ";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What errors is it giving you?

Comment: The using directive is unnecessary for the ServiceReference1, and the WebserviceSoapClient says it could not be found. Is there a place where I need to declare it?